# Please correct my Test class

Tags: apex

```
public without sharing class OpportunityUtility {
    public static void assignAccountToAM(String opportunityId){
        Opportunity oppRec = [Select Id, AccountId,OwnerId,Owner.Account_Manager__r.Id,
            Owner.Account_Manager__c,Account.OwnerId,Account.Owner.Is_Account_Manager__c from Opportunity where Id =: opportunityId];
        if(oppRec.Account.Owner.Is_Account_Manager__c == false && 
                oppRec.Owner.Account_Manager__c != null && 
                        oppRec.Owner.Account_Manager__r.Id != oppRec.Account.OwnerId){
            Account accountRec = [Select Id,OwnerId from Account where Id=: oppRec.AccountId];
            accountRec.OwnerId =oppRec.Owner.Account_Manager__c;
            update accountRec; 
        }
    }
}

@isTest(seeallData=false)
public  class TestClassforOpportunityUtilityclass {

     static void firstOpp(){
        User u1= [select id from User where alias='AUser' AND Is_Account_Manager__c = false limit 1];
      update u1;

        User u2= [select id from User where alias='AaUser' AND Is_Account_Manager__c = true limit 1];
      update u2;


date dt= date.today();  
       dt = dt-90;
       Date dt1 = dt.toStartOfMonth();
       integer noOfDays = date.daysInMonth(dt1.year(),dt1.month());
       Date dt2 = date.newInstance(dt1.year(),dt1.month(),noOfDays);
List<Opportunity> optys= new List<Opportunity>();

Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();
opty.StageName = 'warm';
opty.CloseDate= dt;
opty.CreatedDate=dt2;
opty.Accountid ='aks';
opty.Account.Owner.Is_Account_Manager__c = false;
opty.Account.owner.id = u1.id;
opty.Owner.Account_Manager__r.Id = u2.id;
opty.name='optytest';
opty.Opplead_id__c='testid';
opty.Division__c='Jaguars';
         Optys.add(opty);
 insert optys;

         for(Opportunity loopopp : optys) {
           System.assertEquals(loopopp.Account.owner.id, loopopp.Owner.Account_Manager__c);
             System.debug('loopopp');
           // loopopp.Account.owner.id = optys.get(Owner.id).Account_Manager__c;

         update loopopp;
     }
    }

}
```

Last three line of my class is showing not tested please rectify my test class.

Comment: Where are you even calling the class in your test code (trigger ?) ? Please understand that we expect you to explain what your code is doing and what is blocking you. Currently you're not doing a lot of effort in helping us help you. Without some effort from you it's unlikely that the community will help. Have you already tried something to "debug" or analyse why these lines are not covered ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating your test opportunity, you are not giving the opportunity a real accountId - you need this because the your account query three lines from the end depends on it. If it returns nothing, the remaining lines won't get covered.

You should create a test account record, insert it, do a system.assert to make sure it is inserted, then reference that test record's id when you are creating your test opportunity. See below:

//You might have other required fields on Account in your org - make sure to add those or your assert will fail.

```
Account testAccount = new Account(
    Name = 'Test Account',
    OwnerId = u1.Id
    );

Insert testAccount;

system.assert(testAccount != null, 'The test account did not insert as expected');

List<Opportunity> optys= new List<Opportunity>();

Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();

//Reference test account id instead of aks
opty.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
//opty.Accountid ='aks';
//Remove this line - this is set when you create the test account record. 
//opty.Account.owner.id = u1.id;

 Optys.add(opty);
 insert optys;

@isTest(seeallData=false)
public  class TestClassforOpportunityUtilityclass {

     static void firstOpp(){
        User u1= [select id from User where alias='AUser' AND Is_Account_Manager__c = false limit 1];
      update u1;

        User u2= [select id from User where alias='AaUser' AND Is_Account_Manager__c = true limit 1];
      update u2;


date dt= date.today();  
       dt = dt-90;
       Date dt1 = dt.toStartOfMonth();
       integer noOfDays = date.daysInMonth(dt1.year(),dt1.month());
       Date dt2 = date.newInstance(dt1.year(),dt1.month(),noOfDays);

         Account testAccount = new Account( Name = 'Test Account', OwnerId = u1.Id );
         Insert testAccount;

system.assert(testAccount != null, 'The test account did not insert as expected');

         List<Opportunity> optys= new List<Opportunity>();

Opportunity opty = new Opportunity();
opty.StageName = 'warm';
opty.CloseDate= dt;
opty.CreatedDate=dt2;
opty.Account.Owner.Is_Account_Manager__c = false;
opty.Account.owner.id = u1.id;
         opty.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
opty.Owner.Account_Manager__r.Id = u2.id;
opty.name='optytest';
opty.Opplead_id__c='testid';
opty.Division__c='Jaguars';
         Optys.add(opty);
 insert optys;

         if(!optys.isEmpty()){
         system.debug('oppRecSize = ' + optys.size());
             }

         for(Opportunity loopopp : optys) {
           System.assertEquals(loopopp.Account.owner.id, loopopp.Owner.Account_Manager__c);
             System.debug('loopopp');
           // loopopp.Account.owner.id = optys.get(Owner.id).Account_Manager__c;

         update loopopp;
     }
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, you should do null checks on your lists before you try to loop through them and update the records. It is good to debug the size of your lists, so that you can easily tell if a query is not returning records, and it also will prevent a null pointer. For instance if (!oppRec.isEmpty()){do stuff} with a system.debug('oppRecSize = ' + oppRec.size()) right after the query.

Comment: Hi Bethany thanks for valuable ans, but still those three lines are not tested, please review my updated test class.